# Data disappears after naming column in Spyder

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, spyder

A bit new to this, my data frame returns empty in the variable explorer, whenever I try to change the column name to something, the column change happens, but the data disappears.
I will put the code below, anyone willing to help out please do.

`import pandas as pd`

`h = open("Test_Data.txt")`

`df = pd.DataFrame(h)`

`df1 = pd.DataFrame(h, columns =['Remove, Yaw, Pitch, Roll'])`

Okay so here is my data when I first read it without editing,
[Here is the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjYJn.png)

And here is when I change the column name to something , [2nd link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNmBX.png)

EDIT: I fixed the problem by converting the DataFrame to numpy (Array of objects), and then changing the name of the column, here's the line I used.

`arr = df.to_numpy()`

Comment: what is in `Test_Data.txt` ?

Comment: There is sensor data stored in that file

Comment: It's helpful to provide a small sample of your data. Based on that others can verify the input for your dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem by converting the DataFrame to numpy, and then changing the name of the column, here's the line I used.

`arr = df.to_numpy()`

Answer (score 0):

Don't `open` the text file first, just enter the path in the `read_csv` method of Pandas. This could work, depending on your separator.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('Test_Data.txt', sep=" ", columns=['Remove, Yaw, Pitch, Roll'])
```

Comment: I did what you said, it gave me a Value error, saying **header must be integer or list of integers**

Comment: `headers` should've been `columns`. I edited my answer.